# Express + Node.js with https requests - gives "[Error: socket hang up]"

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, ssl-certificate

I would like to set up a webservice using node.js (v0.8.25) and Express (v3.3.1), both server and client are running node.js.  I require that the connection is secure and that both the client and server can authenticate each other.  When I run the code below I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Here is my server code:

```
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = express();

server.configure(function(){
    server.use(express.bodyParser());
});

// Listen to posts to 127.0.0.1/myroute
server.post('/myroute', function (req, res) {
    // Do some fun stuff, error checking etc
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
    res.end("{Okay}"); 
});

var credentials = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('../ssl/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('../ssl/server.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('../ssl/ca.crt'),
    requestCert:        false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    passphrase: 'test21'
};

var https_server = https.createServer(credentials, server);
server.listen(1337);
console.log('Server running at https://127.0.0.1:1337');
```

Here is the client code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var options = {
          hostname: '127.0.0.1',
          port: 1337,
          path: '/myroute',
          method: 'GET',
          key:    fs.readFileSync('../ssl/client.key'),
          cert:   fs.readFileSync('../ssl/client.crt'),
          ca:     fs.readFileSync('../ssl/ca.crt'),
          passphrase: 'test21' 
};

https.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });

}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: Try changing `server.listen(1337);` to `https_server.listen(1337);`

Comment: @user568109, thanks, I tried that, but I still get the same result.